# Is there a way to know if a message was deleted by channel members before i delete that message myself in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Is there a way for me to know *if the message send by my bot to a channel was deleted before i delete that message* using ***deleteMessage** method in Bot API* in Telegram

`delete_message(channel_ID,message_ID)` *returns true even if the message was already deleted* .
Is there a way to know if the message was already deleted

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage

(This is an advertisement bot so i don't want admins deleting the message until i delete it)

**Any suggestions will be helpful**

**I'm new to telegram API**

Comment: you can try to delete message if get TelegramError in detail you can see, also with telethon you can try to get message and if it was deleted you will get "message not found"

Comment: Deleting message wont give an error if it was already deleted but we can use getMessages and check for errors